# Show form OnClick in NavBar AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my first time coding a project on angularjs and i cant seem to figure out how to leave a form hidden until a certain button is clicked on in the navigation bar. I cannot seem to hide or make the button click properly as I dont have much knowledge on controller objects and other functions in angularjs.  Please help out if yall could. Thanks in advance.

Heres the code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>


    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- The main CSS file -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>



<body ng-app>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <nav class="{{active}}" >

        <a href="#" class="AddItem"  ng-click="showForm = true">Add Item </a>
        <a href="#" class="DeleteItem">Delete Item</a>
        <a href="#" class="DisplayItem">Display Item</a>
        <a href="#" class="BorrowItem">Borrow Item</a>
        <a href="#" class="ReturnItem">Return Item</a>

    </nav>

        <form ng-show="showForm"ng-submit="submitForm()">
            <h1>Add Items</h1>

            <div layout="column"       layout-align="center center">
                <div> <button class="additmbtn" onclick="">Add Book</button></div>
                <div><button class="additmbtn" onclick="">Add DVD</button></div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

        <script>
            var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

            myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',
                function($scope) {
                    $scope.showForm = false;

                    // init empty user object for our form
                    $scope.user = {};

                    $scope.submitForm = function() {
                        // logic when the form is submitted
                        //...
                    };

                }
            ]);
        </script>




</body>
```

Comment: have you imported the "angular.js" <script src=""> ?

Comment: Yes I added it but it still didnt work

Comment: NinjaJami 's answer is correct, I have tried and tested it

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are added **ng-app** multiple times , both in body and div. So Angular JS will throw an error

Just add either in body or div

```
<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

Or

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div  ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

Comment: Its still visible when i boot up the webpage

Comment: @HawkEye i just pasted your code in a plain html, removed  one ng-app and added angular js library. It’s working for me. any error on console??

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine and working perfectly [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yYsbd4iN7YfnWkZm1WSD?p=preview). I have created [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yYsbd4iN7YfnWkZm1WSD?p=preview) of your code. Please check and don't forget to include angular library in your application which was missing. And works as you expect to make the form visible when you click on **Add Item** link.

```
    <nav>
        <a href="#" class="AddItem" ng-click="showForm=true">Add Item</a>
        <a href="#" class="DeleteItem">Delete Item</a>
        <a href="#" class="DisplayItem">Display Item</a>
        <a href="#" class="BorrowItem">Borrow Item</a>
        <a href="#" class="ReturnItem">Return Item</a>
    </nav>
    <form ng-show="showForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
      <h1>Add Items</h1>
      <div layout="column" layout-align="center center">
        <button class="additmbtn" onclick="">Add Book</button>
        <button class="additmbtn" onclick="">Add DVD</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```